# How to append item to match the length of two list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am working on a Python script which is connected to a server. Every x min, server returns two list but the length of these list is not same. For ex:

```
a = [8, 10, 1, 34]
b = [4, 6, 8]
```

As you can see above that a is of length 4 and b is of length 3. Similarly, sometimes it returns

```
a = [3, 6, 4, 5]
b = [8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 3]
```

I have to write a logic where I have to check if length of these two list is not same, then add the `0` at the end of the list which is smaller than other list. So for ex, if input is:

```
a = [3, 6, 4, 5]
b = [8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 3]
```

then output will be:

```
a = [3, 6, 4, 5, 0, 0]
b = [8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 3]
```

What can I try to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement where you  compare the lengths of the two lists?

Comment: If you are working on some code, it is more than ideal - nearly a requirement - to show that work. Please do that if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def pad(list1, list2):
    # make copies of the existing lists so that original lists remain intact
    list1_copy = list1.copy()
    list2_copy = list2.copy()

    len_list1 = len(list1_copy)
    len_list2 = len(list2_copy)
    # find the difference in the element count between the two lists
    diff = abs(len_list1 - len_list2)
    
    # add `diff` number of elements to the end of the list
    if len_list1 < len_list2:
        list1_copy += [0] * diff
    elif len_list1 > len_list2:
        list2_copy += [0] * diff

    return list1_copy, list2_copy


a = [3, 6, 4, 5]
b = [8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 3]
# prints: ([3, 6, 4, 5, 0, 0], [8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 3])
print(pad(a, b))

a = [8, 10, 1, 34]
b = [4, 6, 8]
# prints: ([8, 10, 1, 34], [4, 6, 8, 0])
print(pad(a, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

For now, I can suggest this solution:

```
a = [3, 6, 4, 5] 
b = [8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 3]

# Gets the size of a and b.
sizeA, sizeB = len(a), len(b)

# Constructs the zeros...
zeros = [0 for _ in range(abs(sizeA-sizeB))] 

# Determines whether a or b needs to be appended with 0,0,0,0...
if sizeA < sizeB: 
    a += zeros
else: 
    b += zeros

print(a,b)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use *more_itertools* *padded()* method:
It's prob. more elegant and adaptable for future Use cases.

**Notes:** just need to do `pip install more_itertools` first.

```py
# simple example to demo it:
from more_itertools import padded

print(list(padded([1, 2, 3], 0, 5)))    # last num: 5 is the numbers of 0 to be padded to make the total length to be 5. (needs 2 zeros)

# [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]

# more examples:
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> K = [3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
>>> gap = len(K) - len(L)
# 3
# shorter list is L
>>>list(padded(L, 0, len(L) + gap))
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **extend** instead of **append**. This is the way to add a list to another list in Python. The list here is the list of zeros.

```
a = [3, 6, 4, 5, 9, 3] 
b = [8, 3, 5, 2]
lenA, lenB = len(a), len(b)
diff=abs(len(a)-len(b))
if lenA < lenB: 
    a.extend([0]*diff)
else: 
    b.extend([0]*diff)
print(a)
print(b)
```